# ImageMagick API - export pixels with correct orientation

Tags: imagemagick, magickwand

I've been using this method to export pixels using the MagickWand API:

```
MagickExportImagePixels
```

But, this doesn't appear to obey the orientation exif data in the image. Is there anyway to extract the pixels in the correct orientation, so I can write them out in a different format (Not using `MagickWriteImage`)? Basically, I want the behaviour of the auto-orient option for convert.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am one of the developers for ImageMagick and it seems we forgot to add this method to Wand. The next release of ImageMagick (6.8.9-9) will include the following method that can be used to automatically orient an image:

```
MagickAutoOrientImage(magick_wand);
```

Answer (score 1):

When 6.8.9+ release of ImageMagick with `MagickAutoOrientImage()` is not available I use the following code to auto-orient images:

```
void auto_orient_image(MagickWand* image) {
  PixelWand* pwand=0;
  switch(MagickGetImageOrientation(image))
  {
    case UndefinedOrientation:
    case TopLeftOrientation:
    default:
      break;
    case TopRightOrientation:
      MagickFlopImage(image);
      break;
    case BottomRightOrientation:
      pwand=NewPixelWand();
      MagickRotateImage(image, pwand, 180.0);
    case BottomLeftOrientation:
      MagickFlipImage(image);
      break;
    case LeftTopOrientation:
      MagickTransposeImage(image);
      break;
    case RightTopOrientation:
      pwand=NewPixelWand();
      MagickRotateImage(image, pwand, 90.0);
      break;
    case RightBottomOrientation:
      MagickTransverseImage(image);
      break;
    case LeftBottomOrientation:
      pwand=NewPixelWand();
      MagickRotateImage(image, pwand, 270.0);
      break;
  }
  if (pwand) DestroyPixelWand(pwand);
  MagickSetImageOrientation(image, TopLeftOrientation);
}
```

Might need to add error handling.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only way to do this is pseudo-manually by getting the image orientation and rotating the image accordingly. It's not difficult, but I was hoping a more concise solution was built into the API. An incomplete example follows:

```
OrientationType t = MagickGetImageOrientation(magick_wand);
if (t == RightTopOrientation) {
    MagickRotateImage(mw, pw, 90);
}
...
```